# How to efficiently handle spring boot microservices?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dns, microservices

I have bunch of spring boot microservices running in unique ports. How do we handle these microservices in production ?

In production, we only need the DNS, how do we handle the DNS mapping.

For ex:
*example-microservice-1 (port: 8001)

example-microservice-2 (port: 8002)

example-microservice-3(port: 8003)

example-microservice-4 (port: 8004)

example-microservice-5 (port: 8005)*

I would want something like below,
*myprod.com/example-microservice-1

myprod.com/example-microservice-2*   ...

Instead of,
*myprod:8001/example-microservice-1

myprod:8002/example-microservice-2*

(removed "https/http" above due to less reputation)

All the microservices exists in a different codebase and when build will create individual runnable jars.

Comment: There is just so many options. Research "api gateway". You can build your own with something like Zuul. You can use a service, like Apigee. Just do some research.

Comment: @Strelok Thanks. I have tried zuul. Trying to find a reason to go ahead of nginx (going thru the documentation).

Comment: Yeah just nginx in reverse proxy mode will work just fine too

Comment: API Gateway+ Service Registry (e.g. Netflix Zuul) should be the obvious choice in this case, because you might need to establish inter-service communication in future. nginx should be configured in front of API Gateway. Individual microservices should not be exposed to nginx as it will prevent scaling capabilities of your ecosystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply install nginx and do a reverse proxy to your microservices.

**nginx** example:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name myprod.com;
    location /example-microservice-1 {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
        proxy_set_header Host      $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location /example-microservice-2 {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8002;
        proxy_set_header Host      $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is ideal solution for my use case. But, while trying out different options I came across Netflix Zuul and wondered If that provide anything better.

Answer (score 1):

In case of spring boot application depending on spring cloud dependencies.
Zuul is the right option.

Please go through below guide

https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/

you can find sample application here :

https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/Microservices-workshop

For Documentation Reference: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html